# Push to same git remote using two different URLs

Tags: git

I have a bare repository on my home-server to which I push from my
laptop for backup.  Due to a new router I cannot push anymore from
within my home-LAN to the home-server using the global URL (something
to do with "NAT loopback") but need to use the local LAN address.  So my
.git/config now contains two remotes for the same bare repository:

```
[remote "home1"]
        url = ssh://username@my.url/home/username/git_bare_repos/repo.git
        mirror = true
[remote "home2"]
        url = ssh://username@192.168.1.74/home/username/git_bare_repos/repo.git
        mirror = true
```

So, questions: Is this ok?  Are there potential hazards/pitfalls? And is there a better way to do this, so I wouldn't have to use different commands depending on whether I'm at home or not?

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution to me. I'm not sure why you'd get a `NAT loopback` error though. I think that's the real issue.

Comment: @Stefan: many routers still don't allow/support NAT loopback connections. It occurs when A tries to connect to the public IP address of B (or even to itself), but B is in the same network of A (behind the same router).

Comment: @Stefan: yes, so after swapping the router SSH ceased to work from within the LAN.  Similar to what is described [here](http://www.broadbandreports.com/forum/r25031385-BC-Telus-Optik-V1000H-Actiontec-modem-router-Port-forwarding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ok. They're the same repo after all.

The only difference for you is that depending on your current location you'll have to push/pull/etc from one remote or the other.

Git keeps a reference for every branch, tag, remote-tracking branch, etc. In fact, they are all references to commits, and they have a file representation in `.git/refs/...`.

By comparing these references git knows the status of each branch, tag, etc. For example, if you compare `refs/heads/master` to `refs/remotes/origin/master`, and the branches are not sync'd, then these refs will differ. To find which one is outdated, git can just verify if the remote commit exists in the local branch, and if it does, then the remote branch is outdated. This also allows git to tell you how many commits your local branch is ahead of the remote branch, and vice-versa.

A more in-depth explanation can be found [here](http://book.git-scm.com/7_git_references.html).

Comment: Thanks. Presumably, the local git repository doesn't save any information about the state of the remotes and what it had sent to them previously? As the local repos cannot possibly know what's going on with the remote.

Comment: @Mauro: Updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you pull the latest from `home1`, make some changes, and push them back.  Then you do some work from the other location and go to push them to `home2`.  Git doesn't know `home1` and `home2` are the same repository, but it doesn't matter.  Git sees that `home2` "somehow" already got the changes you pushed earlier  to `home1` and just pushes up your new changes.