# Git: Can I use different URLs for "origin" depending on environment?

Tags: git

I am using a Git host that for network-configuration reasons is accessible via SSH on the local area network, but HTTPS from outside that network. Is there a nice way to be able to switch URLs depending on whether I'm on the LAN or working elsewhere? Having to "flip a switch" once each time I change locations is fine, but I would prefer not to have to remember which remote I am using every time I push or pull. That is, I would prefer to just call the remote `origin` regardless of where I am.

The question [Push to same git remote using two different URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032439/push-to-same-git-remote-using-two-different-urls) seems similar, but is about using two separate remote entries in the configuration.

The best idea I have thought of so far is to use two remotes and then copy-paste the relevant information into the section for `"origin"` when I get home or go into the office.

```
[remote name="origin-office"]
    url = "ssh://me@git.example.com/mystuff.git"
[remote name="origin-home"]
    url = "https://git.example.com/hosted-git/mystuff.git"
[remote name="origin"]
    # Copy-paste stuff from "origin-office" or "origin-home" here.
```

I could even write small shell scripts to do the manipulation of `.git/config` for me.

Is there a nicer way (or at least something that conforms better to Git philosophy) to do this?